# Creating a calculator using operators and dictionaries

Tags: python

I know there are a million question out there like this, but I have yet to find one that calculates more than a simple addition or subtraction of 2 values. My idea is to use a dictionary and operators and math, but I don't quite know how to design the loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
import math
import operator

A=input('input your equation\n')

dict={'cos':math.cos, 'sin':math.sin, 'pi':math.pi,'e':math.exp,'+':operator.add,'-':operator.sub,'*':operator.mul,'/':operator.truediv,'log':math.log}
dict2={}
for x in range(1000):
    dict2[str(x)]=x
dict.update(dict2)
B=A.split()
```

So the idea is the individual can type in any equation, and get the appropriate value out. So sin2+cos5/2*pi or something like that. The issue here is the operators don't exactly translate to + and - functions, instead the format you use is operator(integer1,interger2), whereas the math functions are more math(integer).

The idea I had was the individual would type something like 2 + 2 + 2, and then I split this up and convert each value, the '2' into integers, and the '+' into the addition function. However, this won't work because add is not the same as +. The same goes for the math functions as well.

In addition, the above setup/idea I have comes across another issue. As of now, its simply going to take the strings individually as they come, but this severely limits what the user can input. Ideally, I'd like to have it so the user can input an equation and have it solved, not just a series of strings with functions being applied to them. This would require you to use parenthesis, but my current setup doesn't use that.

I.E. (2+2)/(3+2), which should give 4/5, my current set up would look at it as 4/3+2 (not the same as 4.5).

This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

```
#user input
2 + 2 / 4 + 2
#script then goes through each string and applies operations to them using a loop
#so program reads
'2', '+', '2', '/', '4', '+', '2'
#then using the dictionary, it converts this to:
2+2/4+2
#and, this is python readable, so it would be the same if you just typed the above equation into python
#output
3
```

Comment: What is your _specific_ question? You've described what your program does, but haven't asked anything that would qualify as a [mcve]. If "my current setup doesn't use that" then it sounds like you need to build that functionality

Comment: My question is, how do I create a calculator using a dictionary and operators. I have a basic setup, but my setup comes across some issues. For example, the operator.add is not the same as +, you can't do 2 operator.add 2, that is not the same as 2 + 2. To use the operator, the format should be operator.add(2,2), that'll give you 4. From other answers to questions like these, they define a function where operator.add(integer1,integer2), and then use that in the dictionary, the issue is if the user inputs 2 + 2 +3, then that setup doesn't work. Furthermore, it won't work if you do sin(2)+2

Comment: So what I want to do is set it up so it reads the input left to right, and does operations as they come. I.E. It converts the string input into integers and functions. So if you type '2 + 2' as a string, it converts it 2 + 2.